# Microsoft Windows UVC Extension Unit sample compilation troubleshooting

Tags: c++, windows, usb, directshow, wdk

I have been trying recently to get UVC (USB Video Class) extension unit up and running.I did make some progress (by getting vidcap_i.c by a lead from a message from another forum),but I have not been able to go through due to compilation errors and I hope I could get some help here for the subject.
I have created all the necessary files ,which I was guided by the sample at Microsoft site,except the sample application.

Their content is the same as at the UVC sample link.

*Note:I got a little confused by the line that says "Copy Extend.def from the WIA extend sample and edit it. Uvcxuplugn.def should contain".I hope I got it correctly - I have copied the extend.def file from WDK samples directory to 
c:\xu directory ,edited the file ,added the necessary content and saved it as Uvcuplugn.def file.

After building using the Build environment ,this is the output of the compilation :

C:\xu>Build -cZg

BUILD: Compile and Link for AMD64

BUILD: Start time:

BUILD: Examining c:\xu directory for files to compile.

```
c:\xu Invalidating OACR warning log for 'root:amd64chk'
```

BUILD: Building generated files in c:\xu directory

Configuring OACR for 'root:amd64chk' -

Running MIDL on - interface.idl

BUILD: Compiling c:\xu directory

Compiling - interface_i.c

Compiling - vidcap_i.c

Compiling - uvcxuplgn.cpp

1>errors in directory c:\xu

1>c:\xu\xuproxy.h(69) : error C2017: illegal escape sequence

1>c:\xu\xuproxy.h(71) : error C2059: syntax error : '__uuidof'

1>c:\xu\xuproxy.h(71) : error C2017: illegal escape sequence

1>c:\xu\xuproxy.h(71) : error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name

1>c:\xu\xuproxy.h(71) : error C2011: '' : 'enum' type redefinition

1>c:\xu\uvcxuplgn.cpp(7) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

1>c:\xu\uvcxuplgn.cpp(7) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style
 formal list?)

1>c:\xu\uvcxuplgn.cpp(31) : error C2065: 'ObjectMap' : undeclared identifier

Compiling - stdafx.cpp

Compiling - xuproxy.cpp

Building Library - objchk_win7_amd64\amd64\uvcxuplgn.lib

1>link : error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'c:\xu\objchk_win7_amd64\amd64\uv
cxuplgn.obj'

BUILD: Compile errors: not linking c:\xu directory

BUILD: Finish time:

BUILD: Done

```
12 files compiled - 1 Warning - 8 Errors
1 library built - 1 Error
```

I get the same errors no matter what the target is (x86,x64,ia64)

Now,let's review errors one by one ,starting from the last :

LNK1181->No idea about that error.I have done clean ups of the build and that did not help

at all.But this is probably the easiest error to resolve,hope you would be able to give me

a lead on the subject.

uvcxuplgn.cpp,Line 7 ,the problematic syntax is :BEGIN_OBJECT_MAP(ObjectMap).

According to Microsoft's documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10fb0d3e(v=vs.90).aspx) , this directive is defined at atlcom.h,which is included
 in the file ,so I am really confused about the cause of this error.

The last errors relate to last 5 lines of extension unit proxy header file (cannot post code here due to errors-check this page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568134(v=vs.85).aspx)

Again,no idea ,why it shouldn't compile.Hope I could get some lead on the subject
Sorry for the long post,hope you could help me (and probably many others) who struggle with this Windows UVC extension unit subject

Answer (score 0):

First, you always have to look at the first error that happens. The others are often following errors. So just delete the wrong escape sequence () in line 69 and in line 71 in xuproxy.h.

The linking error only happens, because the compiler couldnt compile the .cpp files earlier, so the object file is missing.